# function to convert String to upper case

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

I have been trying to make a user defined function I wrote return it's value in all upper case, using the `String.ToUpper()` method in VBA. When I try to use my UDF in excel, I get a compiler error that just highlights the top line of my UDF:

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
```

Here is the code in it's entirety:

```
Function removeSpecial(sInput As String) As String
    Dim sSpecialChars As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSpecialChars = "\/:*?™""®<>|.&@# (_+`©~);-+=^$!,'" 'This is your list of characters to be removed
    For i = 1 To Len(sSpecialChars)
        sInput = Replace$(sInput, Mid$(sSpecialChars, i, 1), "")

    Next
    sInput = sInput.ToUpper()
    removeSpecial = sInput
End Function
```

The code works fine to remove special characters, but I would like it to also convert the inputted String to upper case.

I started receiving this error when I tried to add:

```
sInput = sInput.ToUpper()
```

If this code is commented out, my UDF works, but without returning the inputted string in all Upper.

Comment: for VBA (not VB.Net) just use `sInput = UCase(sInput)`

Comment: Well that explains a lot. At least I'm not crazy. Thanks again simoco.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just the wrong function. You want

```
sInput = UCase(sInput)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Answer accepted and the title of the question changed. Hopefully that will make it easy to find for users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the function UCase(...) is working. Here is another example "Capitalize the first letter in the 2nd column from 2nd row till the end":

```
Sub UpCaseMacro()

' Declare variables
Dim OldValue As String
Dim NewValue As String
Dim FirstLetter As String
Dim i As Long

' Select values
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastRow, 2)).Select

' Update data
For i = 2 To Selection.Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
        OldValue = Cells(i, 2).Value
        FirstLetter = Left(Cells(i, 2).Value, 1)
        NewValue = UCase(FirstLetter) & Right(OldValue, Len(OldValue) - 1)
        Cells(i, 2).Value = NewValue
    End If
  Next i
 End Sub
```